# How can one output a PostScript file from a Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, postscript

What libraries/modules exist to output PostScript files from Haskell? The simpler and easier to use, the better. The only two features I need are the ability to draw points and lines.

Comment: PostScript is a Turing-complete programming language (stack based), with a textual representation; so generating it is just a matter of printing. But maybe you want an Haskell interface to the Cairo library?

Comment: Unfortunately PostScript doesn't have native points or lines, you have to simulate them with arcs and paths respectively. If you know PostScript a bit, it is easy to define your own primitives for points and lines then generate simple code to use them. BTW, I'm the author of Wumpus which Daniel Wagner mentioned, it has a rather odd API for building drawings so that it can do some tricks to generate somewhat efficient PostScript (though it could do a lot better). If you want a drawing library I would recommend Diagrams instead if you can live with a Cairo dependency.

Answer (score 5):

A quick Ctrl-F on Hackage finds three packages mentioning PostScript in their description:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hps
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hps-cairo
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wumpus-core

Additionally, the bindings to cairo have facilities for creating PostScript output:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cairo/0.12.3/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:withPSSurface

Perhaps one of these will suit your needs.